# Styling and Listening for items in template Custom Element at Dart

Tags: dart

I'm trying to build equivalent example of [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/#fromtemplate)

the code I used is:

```
class proto extends HtmlElement {
    static final tag = 'x-foo-from-template';
    factory proto()=>new Element.tag(tag);

    proto.created() : super.created(){ 


      // 1. Attach a shadow root on the element.
      var shadow = this.createShadowRoot();

      // 2. Fill it with markup goodness.
      var t = new TemplateElement();
                  t..id="sdtemplate"
                   ..innerHtml = """
                        <style>
                            p { color: orange; }
                          </style>
                          <p>I'm in Shadow DOM. My markup was stamped from a &lt;template&gt;.</p>
                          <button>click</button>
                     """;

       var span = t.content.querySelector('span');
       span.text= "hello "+span.text;

        var btn = t.content.querySelector('button');
        btn..onClick.listen((e) => print('hello'));

       shadow.nodes.add(t.content.clone(true));
    }     
  }
```

The code displayed the statement and button, but the following did not work:
1. Styling, nothing had been styled, I checked with the developer tools, and found this output "Removing disallowed element ",
2.OnClick.listen for the button

any thoughts?

Comment: You are using t.content to query for the button but you are assigning innerHTML to have the HTML. But there is no content element in your template. So you have to fix your HTML code I'd guess.

Comment: not getting you @Robert, what you want me to write instead of the innerHtml?

Comment: to use `t.content` you have to add a `<content>` element to your HTML code...

Comment: not getting you, can you write simple line to illustrate pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that Listening to items in Templates is not possible till the template be cloned and called, and Listeners can be added to the script that is calling the template, this is applicable for both Dart and JS.
to add event listeners to the template items, we have to go one step up, and use Custom Elements instead.